# Nginx fresh install : receving unsollicited requests

Tags: nginx

I just set up nginx on my MacBookPro.

I only have "index.html" files with literally just some "HelloWorld" lines.

I opened the access log, and noticed this strange line:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2017:23:46:24 +0100] "GET //trc.taboola.com/sg/bluekai/1/cm?taboola_hm=bkqDJy99999taT5j HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.2 Safari/603.3.8"
```

How am I getting this?

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 is localhost, so that is coming from your own machine. This could happen with a poorly constructed webpage if you were browsing at the same time you had this server running.

Comment: it seems to be from my machine but how could this particular url be handled by my own server?

Comment: Your machine can't handle it, so it returned a 404.